# Apache leading to system lock/freeze

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos

The conclusion in the title may be wrong given that the problem is close to a year old and just now was I able to get some info on the issue.
This is on a centos 5, running on an old PIII with 384 MB Ram.
Note that before about a year ago, when I don't recall what exactly changed, this same server was working just fine. It may have been an older CentOS on it though.

uname says "Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.18-410.el5.centos.plus #1 SMP Wed May 11 21:46:57 EDT 2016 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux"

The problem presents itself with random freezes, every few days, sometimes twice a day. The freeze is not a real freeze in that if I try to connect with ssh to the server, after a good few minutes, I do get a user prompt and after another very long time, I get disconnected with timeout, so I don't get to enter the password.
But eventually, if I let it "frozen" for a day or two, it completely lock up.

The only solution is a reboot, from the button.

Yesterday I finally got a hint from the physical server in that the HDD led was fully lit at the time of the freeze (didn't notice that before as I wasn't really looking), so I fired up IOTOP to monitor the activity and left it running in a putty window.

Just now it froze up at some point. Here is the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

I see there are a lot of httpd processes, a couple mysqld and the very top one is the jurnaling.

I have no idea how to interpret those percentages in the context of my server freezing up.

I have a strong feeling this is a configuration problem and I should be able to control this by tweaking some configurations but am failing to guess what that is.

I do know that restarting apache every few hours prolongs the time the server is ok. And if my traffic goes up (from a very short few visits a day), then the server gets to freeze up in a matter of hours.

Any pointers in what else to check? Or what configuration to tweak?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you got a backend that's not releasing resources correctly and holding the connections open?

Comment: There's a Joomla site, which has been there for around 3 years and 2 wordpress sites: 1 from 4 years ago and 1 since a couple days ago. The Joomla site was not touched since it was setup, and the WP sites are always up to date with everything. and latest. If tehre would have been a bug introduced in WP about a year ago, I expect it to had been fixed till now. So I don't think it;s related to the sites. There's also a  named running for about 3 years, also not touched since set up. Nothing else is public.

Comment: I do think the problem is in or around apache since at freeze time, at least on the screenshot, there are many processes of it (50 maybe more), and during normal operation there are only 10 or around it. I'm currently reading up on how to debug apache so I can see what the child processes are doing because the access and error logs don't show much.

Comment: It would appear, not yet confirmed, that I was the target of a DoS attack, coming from some russian IP (server being in Romania, not paranoid, I've been attacked by russians before all this NATO s*t).

Comment: That would explain it.

Comment: How I cam to the partial explanation: I setup mod_status and I was shown a lot of POST requests from the same IP on the wp_login page. Since it is my own personal blog that I use by myself, that raised a red flag. SO I simply iptable DROPed the said IP and the server relaxed. If this is a target attack, I expect another IP to soon replace the banned one, as soon as the guy at the other end figures out he got caught. I'm saying that since all the previous attacks on me were from botnets and I could see the huge amount of requests with netstat, unlike this time, so it must be a lonely scriptkid

Comment: You might want to talk to your ISP/hosting provider to see if there is something they can do to help. Explain that you are under a DDoS attack.

Answer (score 0):

Many trial and errors later, I came up to a workaround, since I was not yet able to find the root cause of this. (I mean it seems to be random IP's targeting my server every 1-2 days). I've used the htpd server status page and then the atop utility to see what resources were hogged during the freeze and came to see it was the disk.

So many trials later, I came up with the following script. First, there is a max number of httpd child processes allowed, since in my case, normal operations don't spawn more than 20 child processes.
That check alone isn't sufficient since it happened a few times that it took about 24 hours for the process count to kick in after the server froze.
So there comes the iostat check, which is done 2 times at 5+5 second interval in order to avoid local hdd usage spikes.

```
cnt=`ps -Af | grep httpd | grep -v rotatelogs | grep -v grep | wc -l`
now=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M`

if [ $cnt -ge 40 ]
then
  /usr/bin/wget -q -O /root/apache_status_$now http://<your server here>/server-status
  /sbin/service httpd restart
fi

# your hdd here
dsk=`/usr/bin/iostat -dx /dev/hda 5 2 | grep hda | tail -1 | awk '{print $12}'`

if (( $(echo "$dsk > 98" |bc -l) ))
then
  /bin/sleep 5
  dsk=`/usr/bin/iostat -dx /dev/hda 5 2 | grep hda | tail -1 | awk '{print $12}'`
  if (( $(echo "$dsk > 98" |bc -l) ))
  then
    /sbin/service httpd restart
  fi
fi
```

the above is run in a cron job like so

```
0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58 * * * * /root/monitor-apache.sh
```

Hopefully this will help someone manage similar situations.